# Ruby google_drive gem Problems

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api

https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby

There seems to be an update on google docs. There is now an "Addon" function in NEW google docs. Has someone found a work around for new version of google docs and google_drive gem?

```
require 'google_drive'

session = GoogleDrive.login("username@gmail.com", "password")

# the key is found in the url of a google doc web address
# https://docs.google.com/a/pz7XtlQC-PYx-jrVMJErTcg#gid=0    

ws = session.spreadsheet_by_key("pz7XtlQC-PYx-jrVMJErTcg").worksheets[0]


ws.rows
=> ERRORS
ws[1,1]
=> "test" 

ws[1,1] = "hi"
ws.save()
=> ERRORS
```

does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: There's a little green button on the bottom right of the new google docs screen. 

click that button and "revert to old google spreadsheets"

Answer (score 1):

From the version [0.3.8](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/commit/b9e2c00bb30ee32ad8d5792e63dcb9bacd2465cd) gem supports new Spreadsheets.
Also, you can try **spreadsheer_by_url** method.
For example:

```
require 'google_drive'

session = GoogleDrive.login("username@gmail.com", "password")

ws = session.spreadsheet_by_url('https://docs.google.com/a/pz7XtlQC-PYx-jrVMJErTcg#gid=0').worksheets[0]
```